# Create a layout on a user route

Tags: 8, layout-builder

I'm trying to add a Moderation Dashboard tab to the user page like the [Moderation Dashboard](https://www.drupal.org/project/moderation_dashboard) module, but I can't use [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels). Is it possible to create a layout on a route using layout builder?

I've created the route in `msk_module/my_module.routing.yml` with

```
my_module.moderation_dashboard:
  path: '/user/{user}/dashboard'
  defaults:
    _title: 'Moderation Dashboard'
    _controller: '\Drupal\my_module\Controller\MyModuleDashboardController::index'
  requirements:
    _user_is_logged_in: 'TRUE'
```

And the links task in `msk_module/my_module.links.task.yml` with

```
my_module.moderation_dashboard:
  route_name: my_module.moderation_dashboard
  base_route: entity.user.canonical
  title: 'Moderation Dashboard'
  weight: 30
```

And started the controller in `msk_module/src/Controller/MyModuleDashboardController.php` with

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_module\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;

/**
 * Controller for moderation dashboard.
 */
class MyModuleDashboardController extends ControllerBase {

  /**
   * Display the markup.
   *
   * @return array
   *   Return markup array.
   */
  public function index() {
    return [
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#markup' => $this->t('Hello, World!'),
    ];
  }

}
```

So the tab is where I want it. The contents for the tab are the block views displays from the views from  Moderation Dashboard. I suppose I can use hook_theme() and a template and some small amount of CSS. Just wondering if layout builder can do the same thing as the panel in page manager can do?

Comment: The Layout Builder module works with content entities, which include the User entity, not generic routes.

Comment: To clarify @apaderno's point, the implementations of the LB API in core are focused on fieldable entities, but that doesn't mean you couldn't achieve this using the API yourself. Docs are lacking though. There are tests that prove it should work, search core for "test_simple_config"